# MS SQL view in OE but can't find in query

Tags: sql, join, sql-view

I created a 'new' view, which after a refresh is showing in the object explorer no problem. However in another 'old' view, which the 'new' view is connected to via a full outer join, it cannot find it. I.e. the 'new' view is just red underlined with the message "invalid object name"

Have I missed something incredibly simple here or something more sinister going on??

Cheers,
John.

Comment: Is the error message when you hover over it in red? your description is a little cryptic...  perhaps you just need to refresh your intellisense? Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: That seems to have worked well, thank you. More than one thing to refresh, makes sense...